# Python code within shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

Is there any way we can execute python code block from shell script and get the output as variable and the continue with script execution using those variable.

Comment: explaine what you want to do, what you tried to do and what you are struggling with

Comment: I would like to run a python code within a shell script.

Anyways, this worked for me :
python -c 'import foo; print foo.hello()'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
python -c 'import foo; print foo.hello()'
```

After that, you can use the output in bash as a variable and do with it what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for that matter you can execute any executable script/program and capture output of it as well as the return/exit code of the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

LSOUT=`ls -l /etc/passwd`
echo "Return Code is: [$?]"
echo "Output is: [$LSOUT]"
```

Comment: Actually, I would like to run a python code within a shell script, and would not like to execute python script within a shell script (As I don't want to carry python code file along  with shell code file).

Comment: I doubt that is possible. You cannot use another interpreter within a script without doing an explicit exec. Especially the interpreters/language are totally different as bash and python in your case.

Comment: Actually it worked :
 
[MyServer] # cat tmp.sh 
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/python -c 'print "Hello Suresh";a=2;b=5;c=a+b;print c'
[MyServer] # ./tmp.sh 
Hello Suresh
7
[MyServer] #

Comment: Oh now I understood what you were trying to do. Yes, you passed the python script as arguments via **-c** which is ok in this case as you want to execute very smallish py-script. Also the bash will execute python as a separate executable instance while interpreting the script. I thought you didn't want to execute another program.